# Makefiles in C language

Tags: c, ubuntu, makefile

Hello I'm having a hard time understanding makefiles. I play with them to understand them better but here's the issue:

```
all: main

main: main.o funcIO.o funcMan.o
     $(CC)  -o $@ $^
----------------------------------
funcIO.o: funcIO.c 
     $(CC)  -c -o funcIO.o funcIO.c

funcMan.o: funcMan.o
     $(CC)  -c -o funcMan.o funcMan.c
```

This works regardless if everything below the punctured line is there or not. I'm told that this is the right way to write makefiles but why does it work without the targets funcIO.o and funcMan.o and if it works without them, why do we write them? Can you explain it like I'm 5 years old?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Because they already exists in the build folder, you have not deleted them between builds, probably.

Comment: Alternatively you can use a modern programming IDE that does all this for you and focus on actual programming instead. Make files is a thing of the past, from a console era that ended some 30 years ago.

Comment: @Lundin agree, or just compile everything in one call to the compiler. Computers are fast.

Comment: make has a set of implicit rules by default. make, CMake and other build tools are not "a thing from the past". Nor it is console programming. With the migration of all types of computers to the cloud running on "machines" with no more than a text console, many tasks are back to text I/O using JSON, YAML, XAML or whatever.
And projects are getting bigger and bigger, with hundreds of even thousand of files. So integration with make or CMake is a must for ALL IDEs. e.g. Look at Visual Studio and see the level of support for CMake, ninja, NMAKE built in. And compile everything is not an option.

Comment: @ Lundin Maybe I use Makefiles because that's what is used at work. They are certainly not a thing of the past.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using GNU Make (it might be the same for other Makes), this works due to [built-in rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules). Make already knows how to compile a C source file, and unless you tell it otherwise, it applies this recipe to it:

```
%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c -o $@ $<
```

`$@` is the target of the rule (the filename of the `.o` file) and `$<` is the first prerequisite (the filename of the `.c` file). The other variables have sensible defaults (mostly empty).

Answer (score 0):

The right way to use Makefiles is to keep them as small as possible. Makefiles are about *determining dependencies* and only incidentally can be used to build programs. Here's how I would rewrite your Makefile:

```
all: main

main: main.o funcIO.o funcMan.o
```

And I only put the `all` target there because you had it to begin with. Make has a list of builtin rules that know how to build things given certain files as inputs. If you ask it for a `.o` file, it will look for a file of the same name, but with the extension of `.c`, `.cpp`, `.f77`, etc., and run the rule that builds what you *asked for* using that prerequisite file. You don't even need to specify how to build those, they come for free! It's the more complex relationships (such as a final binary) that need to be spelled out, as shown in my above example. There's a similar rule for building a binary out of `.o` files (assuming one of them has the same name as the binary, which yours does), so you don't need to specify *any* tasks, just the dependencies. You can control how they are run by adjusting special flags:

```
CFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic

main: main.o funcIO.c funcMan.o
main: LDLIBS += -lm
```

This version builds every C-compiled file with those `CFLAGS`, and builds `main` while linking in the `-lm` math library.

If you are building normal C programs, I strongly recommend this approach. Specify the prerequisites of the final binary, and control builds through these Make variables.